# PHP exec ping doesn't properly work on Unix server

Tags: php, unix, server, exec, ping

I want to ping a range of ips on the server that runs Unix

```
exec('ping -c 4 '.$ip, $output, $return_var);
```

Problem is that, it doesn't properly ping the ips that actually gets pinged but can't be found on ns_lookup in cmd. what I mean is that some of these ips gets pinged and some not. On localhost, that runs windows, it works fine.

this is the $output array I get when I ping that ip on server (runs Unix):

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(54) "PING 91.208.144.2 (91.208.144.2) 56(84) bytes of data."
  [1]=>
  string(0) ""
  [2]=>
  string(36) "--- 91.208.144.2 ping statistics ---"
  [3]=>
  string(64) "4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2999ms"
  [4]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

that's the $output array I get when I ping it on localhost (on Windows):

```
array(11) {
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
  [1]=>
  string(43) "Pinging 91.208.144.2 with 32 bytes of data:"
  [2]=>
  string(50) "Reply from 91.208.144.2: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=248"
  [3]=>
  string(51) "Reply from 91.208.144.2: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=248"
  [4]=>
  string(51) "Reply from 91.208.144.2: bytes=32 time=11ms TTL=248"
  [5]=>
  string(50) "Reply from 91.208.144.2: bytes=32 time=8ms TTL=248"
  [6]=>
  string(0) ""
  [7]=>
  string(33) "Ping statistics for 91.208.144.2:"
  [8]=>
  string(56) "    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),"
  [9]=>
  string(46) "Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:"
  [10]=>
  string(48) "    Minimum = 8ms, Maximum = 11ms, Average = 9ms"
}
```

exec and ping is available on server cuz it works perfect with the ips that gets pinged and can be looked up in cmd.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you tested this in a shell on the unix box? I.e. away from PHP.

Comment: yes, and it doesn't get pinged.

Comment: So it's not a PHP issue then? At that rate I'd think this was more suited for [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/).